# Show only 1 term of a current posts taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've been using this code to display the taxonomy term of the current post.

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'custom_cat');
foreach($terms as $term){
    print_r($term->name);
    unset($term);
}
```

Which is fine, except now I have some posts with 2 or more terms associated with them and it's throwing off my layout.

Is there a way that I can show only 1 of the terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more PHP than WordPress, but [`wp_get_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) returns a numerically indexed array, so all you need is basic PHP array syntax to grab the first item.

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'custom_cat');

print_r($terms[0]->name);
```

You don't specify which item you want. This will get you last item:

```
$terms = array_pop($terms);
print_r($terms);
```